# VBA- Function not returning a value to Sub-procedure

Tags: vba, excel, function

I have small VBA program to calculate area of a rectangle .
Using the values in Cell B2 and B3 , i called a function rectangle from sub procedure . I am expecting a area to be calculated in the function and to be returned to the sub procedure . In my case its not happening . Why is that ?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim result As Integer
    a = Cells(2, "B").Value
    b = Range("B3").Value
    result = rectangle(a, b)
    MsgBox ("area of rectangle is " & result)
End Sub

Function rectangle(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
    Dim area As Integer
    area = a * b
End Function
```

Comment: You calculate `area` but do not return it.

Comment: you don't need `area` just use `rectangle = a * b` , so the calling procedure will get the value back

Comment: @gserg i did try to add return area in the Function , it throws me an error

Comment: @Shadi yes it worked fine. But what is the logic behind this ? does it mean everytime i call a function , the returning variable name should also be same as function name??

Comment: Please click the link at the top of your question @ICEMAN.